# c# xml string special characters An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1,

Tags: xml, dataset, character

Please help explain why the dataset cannot read the encoded xml?

```
    string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\" ?>
    <DataSet><node>it's my \"node\" & i like it</node></DataSet>";
    string encodedXml = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(xml);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(New XmlTextReader(new StringReader(encodedXml)));
```

I have checked the link http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx
What i want to do is to **read a string with special characters into a dataset**. 
Anyone could provide the code to **read a string with special characters into a dataset**.
thanks very much

Comment: Does that even compile?  You have unquoted string characters in your string literal... e.g. "1.0"

Comment: Have you tried removing the call to `System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape`? Because the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape.aspx) sais it replaces all the angle-brackets with the escaped version (`&lt;`/`&gt;`) - so `ecnodedXml` is not an xml-document.

Comment: the reason to use System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape is because the ds.ReadXml(New XmlTextReader(new StringReader(encodedXml))) throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

[ds.ReadXml(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360dye2a.aspx) takes a filename of and XML file not a string containing XML

Comment: sorry i missed the XmlTextReader(new StringReader(encodedXml)) in the original post, but the result is the same error.
&lt;node&gt;it&apos;s my &quot;node&quot; &amp; i like it&lt;node&gt;